# System.IO.FileNotFoundException while reading XML file in vb/net

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

While testing/debugging an application; vb.net code fails in the frmMain_Load event. It is trying to load the attribute value of `name` from an XML into a combobox. I have the XML in the project but while testing/debugging the application it is looking for the XML file in the bin\debug folder.

[image: Error Message]

The solution looks like this:

[image: Solution Explorer]

I know that I can move the XML file into the bin\debug folder and the application will work fine but I don't think that I should have to do this... What am I missing?

[image: Application Files]
[image: dice.xml Properties]

Full Path: C:\Users\Troy Pilewski\Source\Repositories\dicebag\dice.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Copy to Output Directory` property of `dice.xml` file to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`.

After that, this file will be automatically copied to output (Debug \ Release) folder on project building.

`Copy if newer` will copy file only if it's source has been edited. All changes made to file in Debug folder are saved until you change the source file.

`Copy always` will replace this file on each build.

Comment: I agree with this, however if the OP doesn't want to copy it to the Debug|Release output folders then clearly the file path is wrong. The application is looking in "...\Debug\dice.xml". I suspect you are using My.Application.Info.Directory as the basis for the file path.